# Google Chrome: strange image artifacts (pixelated, broken)

Tags: google-chrome

I recently encountered a strange behavior in my Google Chrome browser.
Images appear pixelated and broken, but they appear on screenshots and get scrolled so it must be the browser and not my laptop. For example, google search:

[image]

Search icons get something like...distorted? Has anyone encountered that and maybe knows how to fix this?

Comment: Facing same issue man, not sure how to fix this :(

Answer (score 4):

Here's a work around: go to chrome://flags and disable **GPU Rasterization**.
You can use this link: `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization` to get there.

*Thanks to https://piunikaweb.com/2022/02/24/google-chrome-images-distorted-pixelated-after-latest-update-for-some/ for the tip*

Answer (score 3):

Turning off **[GPU rasterization]** and **[hardware acceleration]** is worked for me.
(Windows 10 + Chrome v101.x)

#### Turning off GPU rasterization

1. Go to `chrome://flags`
2. Select '**Disabled**' right side of '**GPU rasterization**'.
3. Restart browser.

#### Turning off hardware acceleration

1. Go to `chrome://settings/system`
2. Move switch off '**Use hardware acceleration when available**'.
3. Restart browser.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Not only icons but some large images as well

Ctrl+refresh seem to solve it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AKzH.png)