# object-fit : cover gives pixelated images on chrome

Tags: css, browser

I have a simple card element that has an `<img>` tag inside. The image has an `object-fit: cover;` property on it. When I'm in chrome it has a very strange pixelated effect on it. FireFox on the other hand draws the picture with no issue. Is this a chrome bug or it is just their rendering algorithm not being very good?

[image: firefox image]
[image: chrome]

on the left the firefox's image, on the right the chrome's one, check the arms and the body.

chrome Version 107.0.5304.107
firefox version 107.0

A workaround would not work, since that would be a fix only on my end.
Here is the same problem on another pc. (Different brand, diferent specs)
The problem still persists. (Chrome on the right, still check the arms)
[image: other pc]

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251416/google-chrome-strange-image-artifacts-pixelated-broken ?

Comment: You can try `image-rendering` but it might just as well be an error on GPU side

Comment: modified the question to answer the comments

Comment: I also tried image-rendering, whose properties are mostly deprecated or not producing any result.

Comment: @AtomicUs5000 Yeah the gpu thing works but it's only client side so doesn't really solve the issue

Comment: You need to post the original image plus the code you are using, because with random images of different sizes and minimal code the issue cannot be reproduced. I'm using Chrome/Edge and Firefox, all versions 109. x64. My test: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/YzjQmrP). The vertical and curved cables of the bridge do not show pixelation, in fact, Chrome smoothens slightly better than Firefox. I made sure to use images with high contrast between light and dark colors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TL;DR: you can only mitigate this effect – `image-rendering` is not predictable

#### Current state 2023-01-18

Apparently, most chromium (blink engine) based browsers (google chrome, opera, vivaldi, brave, ie13/edge etc.) switch between different interpolation methods depending on the required scaling/resize to **optimize rendering performance.**

[image: chrome resizing]

**Left: intrinsic 3000x3000px down scaled to 240x240px**
Looks OK – presumably, a bilinear or bicubic interpolation.

**Right: intrinsic 4000x3000px down scaled and fitted into 240x240px**
Noticeable "jagged" edges – presumably, a simple nearest neighbor interpolation – introduced by additional panning/fitting via `object-fit:cover`

Apparently, chromium based browsers will fall back to a more simplistic nearest neighbor downsampling method when both

- intrinsic and rendered dimensions **as well as**
- intrinsic and rendered aspect ratio

differ significantly.

#### Workaround: avoid excessive resizing by optimizing images

- avoid unnecessarily high resolutions - try to resize and crop your images to match the actual layout dimensions: e.g. if you image is always used in an 1/1 aspect ratio - you better crop a 16/9 image. In google light house lingo:  *"Serve images that are appropriately-sized to save cellular data and improve load time."*
- define responsive image and/or Art-Direction image candidates:
  [Smashing magazine: Responsive Images Done Right: A Guide To  And srcset](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/)

However, the aforementioned approaches will only mitigate this effect.

Hopefully, we'll see a better support /implemention as specified for the `image-rendering` values like `smooth` or `high-quality`.

[MDN web docs: image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#examples)

#### Example snippet (just for comparison/testing)

```js
function replaceImg() {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  images.forEach((img) => {
    let wNative = img.naturalWidth;
    let hNative = img.naturalHeight;
    let wRendered = img.offsetWidth;
    let hRendered = img.offsetHeight;
    let scale =
      Math.min(...[wRendered, hRendered]) / Math.min(...[wNative, hNative]);

    if (scale < 0.3) {
      scale *= 2;
      (async() => {
        let dataUrl = await imageToDataURL(
          img.src,
          wNative * scale,
          hNative * scale
        );
        img.src = dataUrl;
        img.classList.add("imgDataUrl");
      })();
    }
  });

  async function imageToDataURL(imageUrl, width, height) {
    let img = await fetch(imageUrl);
    img = await img.blob();
    let bitmap = await createImageBitmap(img);
    let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas") ? document.querySelector("canvas") : document.createElement("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
    let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    return dataUrl;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

figure {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.obj-contain {
  object-fit: none;
  object-fit: none;
}

.pixelated {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.crisp {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

.auto {
  image-rendering: auto;
}

.imgDataUrl {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="replaceImg()"> Replace with dataURL</button></p>


<figure>
  3000 x 3000: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/3000/3000" alt="">
</figure>


<figure>
  4000 x 3000: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/4000/3000" alt="">
</figure>

<figure>
  1200 x 1000: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/1000/800" alt="">
</figure>

<figure>
  240 x 240: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/240/240" alt="">
</figure>

<figure>
  300 x 240: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/300/240" alt="">
</figure>

<figure>
  600 x 480: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/600/480" alt="">
</figure>



<figure>
  3000 x 1500: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/3000/1500" alt="">
</figure>
<figure>
  1600 x 800: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/1600/800" alt="">
</figure>
<figure>
  800 x 400: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/800/400" alt="">
</figure>

<figure>
  600 x 300: auto
  <img class="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/600/300" alt="">
</figure>


<figure>
  800 x 400: pixelated
  <img class="pixelated" src="https://picsum.photos/id/76/600/300" alt="">
</figure>
```

[Codepen example for testing](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/YzjQoyv)

#### »Crispness is in the eye of the beholder«

Even tough there are a lot of options for pixel interpolation (fast bilinear, bicubic, lanczos, b-spline, AI/DL trained algorithms etc.).

Let's be fair:

- some users will prefer slightly "jagged" edges to slightly "blurry" ones
  (trivia: has been a huge thing, when cleartype and other font
  anti-aliasing technologies were introduced – I'm glad the anti-aliasing front won this war ...)
- the latter ones will complain about blurry rendering.
  See also [SO questions tackling the opposite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chrome%20blurry%20image)
- others - using high pixel density displays - might not notice the aforementioned "lazy" optimization tricks at all

As commented by **@Rene van der Lende:**
Chromiums downscaled image rendering isn't per se bad – sometimes firefox (or safari and non-apple webkit browsers like epiphany or midori) might struggle with similar issues **but on other occasions.**

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the up/down sampling of the pixels: *nearest neighbour/preserve details/smoothen* like the Photoshop options for resizing images. Something has to give, right? Hence my request to OP for posting the original image. BTW, Firefox has its issues too in certain cases... You got my vote!

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid we'll never more reliable rendering options. A list of options similar to Photoshop's would indeed be way more intuitive (e.g. none, nearest-neighbour, billinear, bicubic etc) "-webkit-optimize-contrast" is my favorite semantic atrocity.

Answer (score 9):

You should try :

```css
overflow-clip-margin: unset;
overflow: visible;
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your image CSS:

transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0.1px);

You wont see the difference except your pixels are gone :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).