# Why does object-fit impact my image quality and how to avoid it

Tags: html, css, object-fit

Using `object-fit: cover` has a bad impact on my image quality.

We can see that when the element uses `object-fit: cover` the hair in the image gets pixelated.

[image]

Here's a demo of my code: https://codepen.io/widness/pen/NWBywgy

I don't understand why the quality is worse and how to avoid this effect.

### Additional

- The problem isn't the image quality itself -> [here is the image](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/teen-girl-makes-grimace-consternation-20146520.jpg)
- The loss of the image quality is quite subtle, focusing on the light part of the hair makes it more visible

Comment: just my opinion here, anyway it seems to me it's actually the picture itself to be noisy and since it gets scaled to fit into the given width while keeping aspect-ratio, those very noisy area can suffer the problem in a way difficult to predict. But even when looking at the picture at full size 1:1 the hair part is a mess and such mess is magnified by jpg compression. Did you try with a better picture?

Comment: the only thing coming to my mind that would attenuate the issue is to just blur the picture with something like `filter: blur(.6px);` but that's not what you are asking

Comment: It would be important to mention that in the question: The source image is bigger than presented in both cases, right?

Comment: In the "not fit" example, your image size is 180x180 px, which means a ratio of 1:1 (and your original image is 800x800 which is 1:1 too). In the "object fit" version, your image is 180 x 202 which means a different aspect ratio. So you are not *only* resizing the image, you are also distorting it. If I set the width to `auto` in your `.object-fit img` CSS rule, I don't see the same issue.

Comment: @DiegoD: Yes, but the picture quality is not the problem. and having a worse quality sometime reduce the problem. Fact being, to more high quality, the more pixel that could end up being white with the object-fit. And no, blur is not an option here '^^

Comment: @Andy Yes it is, I wouldn't need to object-fit in case it wouldn't.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, this is the reason why I would have liked to use the `object-fit`, that say the image isn't distorted, because `object-fit: cover` keep the ratio. _For what I know_

Comment: Actually @RaphaëlBalet that’s not entirely true if I understand correctly. As soon as one dimension is bigger than the image, it will be scaled while keeping the ratio. So you can have use for `cover`, while not both dimensions of the image are larger than the container. In your case, both dimensions are bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that's just how the browser handles downscaling: [object-fit : cover gives pixelated images on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502978/object-fit-cover-gives-pixelated-images-on-chrome). Whenever I stumble upon a sharpness issue the first I always try is a translate3d and it solves it most of the time. In your case I'm not sure it fixes it 100% but it does look better.

If you can, try to use a picture that has a width and height closer to it's final rendering size, those always render better (seen in second example - scroll down to see it)

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.object-fit,
.object-notFit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 220px;
  width: 180px;
}
picture {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
 .object-fit img {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
<div class="object-notFit">
<picture class="object-notFit">
  <img alt="image" class="contactsCard-img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/teen-girl-makes-grimace-consternation-20146520.jpg" style="
    object-fit: initial;
    height: unset;
">
</picture>
  object not fit
  </div>

<div class="object-fit">
<picture>
  <img alt="image" class="contactsCard-img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/teen-girl-makes-grimace-consternation-20146520.jpg" style="
    object-fit: initial;
    height: unset;
">
  
</picture>
  object fit
</div></div>

<h1>Downscaled</h1>
<div class="example-container">
<div class="object-notFit">
<picture class="object-notFit">
  <img alt="image" class="contactsCard-img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/nVKnTMFJ/rsz-imageimage.jpg" style="
    object-fit: initial;
    height: unset;
">
</picture>
  object not fit
  </div>

<div class="object-fit">
<picture>
  <img alt="image" class="contactsCard-img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/nVKnTMFJ/rsz-imageimage.jpg" style="
    object-fit: initial;
    height: unset;
">
  
</picture>
  object fit
</div></div>
```

There's also an `image-rendering` property but it doesn't seem to help here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering?retiredLocale=de

PS: I think the extremely smooth image on the left is partly an error. The browser introduces a tiny little bit of blurring while downscaling. If you look at the full scale image in another tab you notice that even that isn't as smooth as the thumbnail on the left.

Comment: Thx, the linked issue gave me the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75120770/11135174