# Why does Chrome pick a larger image when there is a better one in srcset in this example?

Tags: html, responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

I am trying to understand the basics of responsive images.

I have this very simple webpage:

http://chubby-orange-fox.s3-website.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive</title>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<img srcset="https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=0.1&amp;w=2000 200w,
https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=0.2&amp;w=2000 400w,
https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=0.4&amp;w=2000 800w,
https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=0.6&amp;w=2000 1200w,
https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=0.8&amp;w=2000 1600w,
https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=2000 2000w" title="test image" alt="test image" aria-label="test image" width="350" height="197" loading="lazy">

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `srcset` contains 6 different images and they have the sizes `200w` (200px), `400w` (400px), `800w` (800px), `1200w` (1200px), `1600w`(1600px) and `2000w`(2000px).

However, as you can see, I have explicitly also added `width="350px"` on the `<img>` tag, Chrome knows the image will be displayed with a width of 350px.

So if Chrome acknowledge that the image will be rendered with a width of 350px:

[image]

Why is it picking the `https://www.datocms-assets.com/58071/1637680873-dadandchildbywindow-edited.png?auto=format&dpr=0.6&w=2000 1200w` version that is `1200px` large, when there is clearly a `400w` (400px) version that is more suited?

Comment: You have to add sizes to the src, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: Are you sure? Because "sizes" is relevant to the viewport size, is it not? While this is a fixed image width

Answer (score 0):

In these responsive times, `width="350" height="197"` is now more used by the browser to know the image width/height ratio than the actual rendered dimensions in CSS pixels.

With `w` descriptors in `srcset`, the browser needs a `sizes` attribute to know which is the target rendered width. If `sizes` is missing, the fallback value is `100vh`, the full viewport width.

If you really want a fixed rendered image width, you should:

- either add `sizes` with said fixed width in CSS pixels
- or use `x` descriptors instead of `w` descriptors in `srcset`

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with this problem where I got the biggest image. I ended up converting the image to 16:9 ratio, the same as the display ratio. This resulted in showing a smaller `srcset` version than the old ratio (500∶243).

I also had a issue with the image being quite pixelated, probably because it was a big image compressed into a small element. This issue went away after changing the ratio and getting a smaller resolution. Later I found an explanation here:
[object-fit : cover gives pixelated images on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502978/object-fit-cover-gives-pixelated-images-on-chrome)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34251103)